# multiplying a scalar by a boost.units.quantity (automatic type conversion issues?)

Tags: c++, boost, boost-units

This is a really minimalist example. I'm using **Boost.Units** in the following way:

```
#define REAL double
...
using namespace boost::units;
quantity<si::velocity, REAL> v;
```

then sometimes I need to have something like

```
quantity<si::velocity, REAL> v_halved;
v_halved = 0.5 * v;
```

This works ok, because the compiler treats `0.5` as `double`. But, when `REAL` is something different then I get a compile error, e.g. if I changed the definition of `REAL` to `long double` the compile complains:

```
error: no match for ‘operator*’ in ‘5.0e-1 * v’
/usr/include/boost/units/detail/one.hpp:58: note: candidates are: boost::units::one boost::units::operator*(const boost::units::one&, const boost::units::one&)
```

Looking into the **Boost.Units** [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/doc/html/boost_units/Reference.html#header.boost.units.quantity_hpp) I founded that the `operator*` is overloaded as follows:

```
// runtime scalar times quantity 
template<typename Unit, typename X> 
  multiply_typeof_helper< X, quantity< Unit, X > >::type 
  operator*(const X & lhs, const quantity< Unit, X > & rhs);
```

Although it is clear from the definition that the scalar and the internal type of the quantity must be the same, I would expect that the compiler automatically converts the type when the conversion can be done implicitly (like from `double` to `long double`). However I think that I might be missing something because the automatic type conversion certainly works for other simple functions like `long double f(long double const & ld)`.

My problem is that I have used expressions like `v_halved = 0.5 * v` quite a lot and my project has become considerably large already, and it is only now, after having to define `REAL` as `long double` that I realize this is a problem. So, I was wondering about a workaround/solution to this, I'm aware that `static_cast<REAL>(0.5)` would be a solution, but I still feel that I'm missing something about the compiler not being able to automatically convert the scalar to the right type.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

template functions are different that non template function. Compiler decide to select template function without considering the implicit casting/promotions. It just look for exact matching.

This is how C++ works in this area.

To get exact matching you would need such `operator *` definition (notice this extra template param Y):

```
template<typename Unit, typename X, typename Y> 
  typename multiply_typeof_helper< X, quantity< Unit, X > >::type 
  inline operator*(const Y & lhs, const quantity< Unit, X > & rhs)
{
    return static_cast<X>(lhs) * rhs;
}
```

but I am afraid that will interfere with boost definition of `*`. You can play with this - like define your own `quantity` which will derive almost entirely from boost - but define multiplication in different way, proposed by me.

Just decide what is easier for you to go with

- do static cast (or better just add `L` - `0.5L` to make long double constant)
- or do some combinations with templates.

Comment: If for this case the compiler looks for exact match, then that explains the problem. As you mentioned, maybe adding a new definition of `operator*` might interfere with the original definition, so this is probably a decision of the authors of the library. Then I think I will stick to the `static_cast<REAL>` solution, since using `0.5L` would be type-specific.